# Is it possible to Flash BIOS to F.34 Intel via Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, intel, bios

Is it possible to Flash BIOS to F.34 Intel via Ubuntu?

My current BIOS version is F.29.

If so, what sort of download am I looking for?

What packages would be required to achieve this?

Where could I find these types of packages?

---

^
**Answers to any of the above questions would be greatly appreciated.** ^

---

Comment: http://www.freedos.org/download/  and here http://www.chtaube.eu/computers/freedos/bootable-usb/

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about F.34 or whatever version you have, but usually there are no programs to update BIOS from any Linux. Just yesterday I updated one BIOS. I had to make a bootable DOS key and put the programs for flashing and new version on the key to do it.